# Paypal RefundTransaction API Operation (NVP) failing

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to hit the live `paypal` URL - `https://api.paypal.com/nvl` with valid login credentials.
But the call is failing with error -

```
A timeout error occurred whilst performing an SSL socket
operation - java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

we are calling the interface using `WMB` and have setup the certificates in the `truststore`.

Comment: Is your SSL Encryption 2048-bit? PayPal changed from 1024 bit key certificates to 2048-bit.

Comment: How to check this. I have recently imported the paypal certs into my server truststore. ( like 2 weeks back )